# OutOfMemoryError in com.google.android

Tags: android, google-analytics, out-of-memory, adsense

Can anybody help me with exception in my Android app. I use Google Analytics and have exception:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at com.google.android.d.d.g.a(SourceFile:51) at com.google.android.d.c.k.b(SourceFile:432) at com.google.android.d.c.c.a(SourceFile:241) at com.google.android.d.c.a.f.b(SourceFile:311) at com.google.android.d.c.a.f.a(SourceFile:108) at com.google.android.d.c.h.c(SourceFile:615) at com.google.android.d.d.s.run(SourceFile:242) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

I'm using google analytics and google interstitial and bottom banner ads version 8.1.0 in my android app.

Comment: I suggest memory profiling your code via MAT and hprof dumps. You can generate hprof dumps from Android Device Monitor, then you'll have to convert them to a format MAT can understand. The tool for converting can be found in your Android SDK/platform-tools/hprof-conv.exe (in my case its in User\AppData\Local\Android\SDK ... If you got some more logging info from before the exception you'll have an idea where it blows up, so you could start in that vicinity. Though the actual problem might be somewhere else in your app entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Your application uses too much memory - that's the basic explanation. There can be many reasons for that, but in general all of them are just memory leaks or (more frequently) long living objects. Use memory analyzer in Android Studio to get more information about places where problem starts. you should also read this Google's article: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html